# show chat message two times on the sender side Broadcast to others

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis

I'm developing a chat application using laravel+socet.io+redis and i used MYSQL for store chat messages.

all processes are working properly.but i facing one of trouble.
that is,

when sender sent a message to the chat room, that message first store database and after that message goes to other client thought redis event.

so, in that case, one message repeat two times on the sender side window. other clients chat room working properly.
below I attach two images for sender and receiver side windows.(*they are in same chat room)

[Sender side window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCzGF.png)

[Receiver side window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OFpm.png)

this is my HTML,redis+nodeserver coding part

```
<html>
  <body>

   <div id="data">
     @foreach($messages as $message)
     <p id="{{$message->id}}">database_<strong>{{$message->Sender}}
   </strong>: 
     {{$message->MessageTxt}}</p>
     @endforeach
   </div>

  <div>
  <form action="sendMessaged" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
Name: <input type="text" name="Sender">
<br>
<br>
Content: <textarea name="MessageTxt" rows="5" style="width:100%">
</textarea>
<button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
 </form>
```

```
 <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:6001');
     socket.on('chat:message',function(data){
      console.log(data)       

       if($('#'+data.id).length == 0){
        $('#data').append('<p>else__<strong>'+data.Sender+'</strong>: '+data.MessageTxt+'</p>')
    }
    else{

    }
});
```

```
    var io = require('socket.io')(6001);
    console.log('Connected to port 6001');
    io.on('error',function(socket){
    console.log('error')
    });
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis(1000);
 redis.psubscribe("*",function(error,count){
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
 console.log('coonected with'+socket.id)
});
redis.on('pmessage',function(partner,channel,message){

message = JSON.parse(message);
socket.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
console.log('Sent')
});
```

Comment: You have to do this on client side because there is proxy involved in between

Comment: i implement an API for the connect to the clients .so how i handle it

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to

```
socket.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

to This

```
socket.broadcast.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

For your information I have listed all the possible scenerios

sending to sender-client only

```
socket.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to all clients, include sender

```
io.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender

```
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel), include sender

```
io.in('game').emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to sender client, only if they are in 'game' room(channel)

```
socket.to('game').emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', include sender

```
io.of('myNamespace').emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

sending to individual socketid

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: levaral thanks for your help.i try to these way.but same problem,

Comment: @androidpc as I already told you... you are behind the proxy so you have to this on client side